# How to capture GET argument on static page

Tags: pages, page-template

So, I want to add some dynamic properties to my static page.

Url of my page is `mysite.com/pagename`, so I've created template `static-pagename.php`.

I'd like to capture get argument if I go to my page by this url `mysite.com/pagename?var=test`.

I have tried with `$_GET['var']` and `get_query_var('var', 'novar');` but it doesn't work. I'm assuming that wordpress is overriding / rewriting those values, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Figured it out. I had to register new query variable in my `functions.php`.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_qvs' );

function register_qvs( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'my_new_var_name';
    return $qvars;
}
```